# How to fix DHCP giving out numerous bad addresses

Tags: networking, dhcp, ip-address

Where I work we have run into a major issue a few times in the past month. Our DHCP server will randomly start filling up with BAD_ADDRESS. We have 3 sections in the subnet. (4.x, 5.x, and 6.x) Aside from a few at the beginning and end of each that we reserve for printers, servers, and the like, all addresses are available for DHCP to hand out. Reserved addresses are not affected, but today we had 241 IPs that were labeled BAD_ADDRESS by DHCP. After deleting them to try to fix the issue, they are back in less than a minute. The only fix we've found so far is to let it ride itself out, which usually takes about two days. This is the third time this month and the second time in a week this has happened. It has happened before but about six or seven months ago, and it fixed itself in a couple of hours instead of days.
This is a major issue that has caused severe problems where I work. Does anyone know what might be causing this and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: ... Any particular DHCP server/daemon?

Comment: The OS is Windows Server 2003. I guess its what comes with that. The server was setup well before I started working there, so I'm not exactly sure. The target path on the shortcut is %SystemRoot%\system32\dhcpmgmt.msc /s

Comment: Are you using a ARP proxying software such as an ASA firewall? (In which case it might be [this](http://johntear.tumblr.com/post/17028050150/bad-address-entries-in-dhcp-database)).

Comment: not that I know of. The only firewall that might be in place is Windows Firewall, but I'm almost positive it's turned off.

Comment: The same event has happened twice more since the original posting. Very frustrating. As before, we have no clue as to the cause or the solution; we just have to let it run its course. It has fixed itself the next day both times. Please any help is greatly appreciated.